# Java string validation

Tags: java, regex

I'm finding a regular expression which adheres below rules.

Allowed Characters

Alphabet : a-z A-Z
Numbers : 0-9

I am using `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` but when call

```
regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" ;  
String key = "message";
    if (!key.matches(regex))
                message = "Invalid key";
```

system will show Invalid key, The key should be valid. Could you please help me?

Comment: What does your regex do? What does `String#matches` do?

Comment: Note that `[^chars]` will match exactly one character that is not one of the `[chars]`. And also note that `String#matches` acts as if your regex is `^regex$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would allow one or more alphanumeric characters,

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Your regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, matches a single character but not of a alphanumeric character. `[^..]` called negated character class which do the negation of chars which are  present inside that character  class.

You don't need to give start or end anchors in the regex when it is passed to `matches` method. So `[A-Za-z0-9]+` would be enough.

**Explanation:**

- `^` Anchor which denotes the start.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` , `+` repeats the preceding token `[A-Za-z0-9]` one or more times.
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: If I want include space beside alphabet and number, what is the correct regex for this case?

Comment: post some example strings.

Comment: ex: I want to allow "Stack over flow 1"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to allow these characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` you should not use  `^` since it negates what is inside the `[]`.

This expression `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` means anything that is **not** a-z A-Z or numbers : 0-9.

You may have seen the `^` being used outside the `[]` at the begging of a regular expression to indicate the begging string like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remove the not-operator. Here is the same example, only the variable is renamed:

```
invalidChars = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" ;  
String key = "message";
if (key.matches(invalidChars)) {
  message = "Invalid key";
}
```

(However, the negated logic is not very readable.)

Answer (score 0):

Try below `Alphanumeric regex`

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]$"
```

**^** - Start of string

**[a-zA-Z0-9]** - multiple characters to include

**$** - End of string

Comment: Doesn't it matches `""`(empty string) and therefore is not meeting the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

With validation use \A \z anchors instead of ^ $:

```
\\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\z
```